# Remove Time From DateTime Property in @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to remove the time from a DateTime property in Razor

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DATE_OF_BIRTH)
```

I tried `model.DATE_OF_BIRTH.Date`,`model.DATE_OF_BIRTH.Date.ToShortDateString()`

But showing Errors.

Comment: Please elaborate on the error you are receiving

Answer (score 4):

You could decorate your view model property with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DATE_OF_BIRTH { get; set; }
```

and then the `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DATE_OF_BIRTH)` helper will display the value respecting the format you defined.

If you are not using view models and cannot modify your domain model you could use the TextBox helper:

```
@Html.TextBox("DATE_OF_BIRTH", Model.DATE_OF_BIRTH.ToShortDateString())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with .Net 6.0. The previous solution didn't worked until I added the [DataType(DataType.Date)] attribute also.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DATE_OF_BIRTH { get; set; }
```

```html
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DATE_OF_BIRTH)
```